# JQuery loop hide items

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each, show-hide

I want to show only 4 item and hide other items. how i can do it

```
$(".item").each(function(i, e){
      if(i == 4 ){
          $(this).addClass("hide");
      }
  })
```

Comment: witch four do you wanna show and witch ones not?

Comment: Is 4 a constant value for what you want to do? Is it fourth item and below that you want to hide? When do you want to show them again?

Comment: i want to hide menu items  after 4. item

Comment: In pure jQuery you would do `$('.item').slice(3).addClass('hide')` or use `:gt()` inside the query; you could use `.hide()` as well, unless the `hide` class does something else

Comment: thanks @Ja͢ck it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per syntax,
if you write `i == 4` only at 4th loop it will hide.
you have to write `i > 3` because array starts from zero(0), which will hide all after 4 items

```
$(".item").each(function(i, e){
      if(i > 3){ 
         $(this).addClass("hide");
      }
})
```

Or simply you can do this:

```
$('.item').slice(3).addClass('hide')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you want to show only the *first* four, or a particular four, but your code attempt suggests the former.

In which case, you don't need JavaScript at all - you can do it from CSS.

```
.item:nth-of-type(4) ~ .item { display: none; }
```

If for some reason you wish to do it with JS nonetheless, you could do:

```
$('.item:nth-child(4)').nextAll('.item').hide();
```

Comment: You're welcome. [That is what happens](https://jsfiddle.net/4pnoyu8s/).